# R code for CV leave one out, fitting only one linear model

Tags: r, linear-regression

I have a data set where I want to calculate the cross validation leave one out mean squared error, where I fit log(y) to 6 explanatory variables.

I can only fit one linear model and I need to work it out for 64 possible models for my data set. My data is y and x1-6. I know there should not be a linear model fitted within my function.

My best guess is to use the dredge function somehow?

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. Could you please make your question reproducible: include a minimal dataset in the form of an object for example if a data frame as df <- data.frame(…) where … is your variables and values or use dput(head(df)). Include the code you have tried and set out your expected answer. These links should be of help: [mre] and [ask]

Comment: Look into the [caret](https://topepo.github.io/caret/) package (easier imo, more mature) or [tidymodels](https://www.tidymodels.org/) (newer, in line with tidyverse coding practices)